# How to keep index straight when ajax request are async and not finishing in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am interacting with the Vimeo oembed api getting videos.  My context is that I have multiple events each with a set of videos.  I am keeping page load times down by simply getting the first set of videos rather than loading all of them.

This function takes 4 parameters and then gets the video, returning the result to the calling function for loading.  The videoUrl is http://www.vimeo.com/VIDEOID, the index is based on a .each in the calling function which is iterating through available ID's, the count is a total number of videos that will be called and the callback handles the data getting back to the calling function.  Once the function is all done it calls showFirstVideo which shows a video for the first thumbnail I am generating.

the issue I am having is that because the ajax calls are async, the indexEq var jumps around.  instead of: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... it will be 1,6,3,0...

I need the indexEq to increment in order so that at the end I can run the showFirstVideo function at the appropriate time.

```
function loadVideo(videoUrl, index, vidsCount, callback) {
    var indexEq = index;
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json",
            data : {"url" : videoUrl },
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(result) {
                index++;
                callback(result);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                var s = "";
                $.each(error, function(name, value){
                    s += name + ": " + value + "\n";
                });
            }
        })
    ).done(function(){
        console.log(indexEq);
        if(indexEq === vidsCount){
            $('.video-thumbs').velocity("fadeIn");
            $('.past-concert-loader').velocity("fadeOut");
            showFirstVideo();

            // RESET INDEX, FOR WHEN WE HAVE TO CALL THIS FUNCTION AGAIN.
            console.log("Trigger indexEq back to 1");
            indexEq = 1;
        }
    });
}
```

The $.each that calls  this function:

```
$.each(vids, function(i, val){
        var videoUrl = 'http://www.vimeo.com/'+val+'';
        loadVideo(videoUrl, i, vidsLength, function(result){
            $('.video-thumbs').append('<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 video-thumb video-'+i+'" data-video-id="'+ result.video_id +'"><img src="'+ result.thumbnail_url +'" alt="'+ result.title +'" class="img-responsive"></div>');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you calling `loadVideo()` inside a loop?

Comment: Just added the $.each for reference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare indexEq as a Global Variable outside this function.  And increment the indexEq value every time the AJAX is called.  This will ensure that you get the values in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this, but this isn't one of them. It looks like you're expecting `indexEq` to hold some state over multiple calls to the function, but it gets re-initialized every time - so all you're doing here is ensuring that `showFirstVideo` is called after the AJAX call for the last video returns, regardless of where it is in the sequence.

One reasonable option here is to use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), which will take a bunch of deferred objects (e.g. the `jqXHR` object returned by `$.ajax`) and fire a callback when they're all resolved. Something like:

```
function loadVideo(videoUrl, callback) {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
    // return the request object
    return jqXHR;
}

// make an array of requests
var allRequests = vids.map(function(vid) {
    var videoUrl = 'http://www.vimeo.com/'+val+'';
    return loadVideo(videoUrl, function(result){
        // ...
    });
});

// do something when they're all done
$.when.apply($, allRequests).done(function() {
    showFirstVideo();
});
```